# Restoring Ribbon tabs in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I accidentally lost all the tabs at the top of the worksheet, except for File and Home (on all spreadsheets).  Do you know how I can get them back?

Answer (score 2):

Go to:

```
file -> options -> customise ribbon
```

and then tick the boxes that you would like on the ribbon

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my problem was that the Formatting Ribbon can be pinned. If you accidentally hit the far right hand side at the bottom of the ribbon there is an arrow pointing up. To retrieve the ribbon you only need to left click on this and then press the pin to retrieve it. 
It is a similar arrow to the one you have on the formula space when writing lengthy formulae. 
Hope this helps

Comment: I’m glad you solved your problem. However, I believe that *your* problem is different from the one that *this question* is about. Also, I don’t understand what you’re saying. I have Excel 2013 — do you? Please do not respond in comments; if you believe that your answer is correct and relevant, [edit] it to make it clearer and more complete.